# Does the way of rxjs6 import dramatically increase the size of the application bundle

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Our angular project tslint

```
"import-blacklist": [
        true,
        "rxjs"
]
```

So if i import as rxjs6, it will show this is blacklisted. When i searched for the reason of including rxjs will import all the Rx functionality and increase the application bundle side.

So currently for Observable, Observer it import as

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
```

I want to use the `Observable.empty();` but it will cause error

> rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.Observable.empty is
>   not a function

```
import { empty } from 'rxjs/Observable/empty';
```

I can directly call `empty()`. But the `import { empty }` in the editor shows that it is deprecated.

After searching in rxjs 6, it should `import { empty } from 'rxjs'`.

So i would like to ask about how to fix this import { empty } deprecation without increasing the application bundle size. Does import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs' really increases the size?
If it import from 'rxjs', then i can use Observable.empty(). It has no problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may find the information [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) useful.

Comment: There is nothing to fix, and using that import won't dramatically increase the production bundle size, because unused functions will be tree-shaken. (if only there was a way to test it! oh wait...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use empty the preferred way is to use the [empty constant](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY)

So you would have

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

foo$.pipe(() => EMPTY).subscribe(() => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use empty with the latest versions of RxJs :

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
...
return EMPTY
```

Quote [rxjs-dev.firebaseapp](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com).

> The same Observable instance returned by any call to empty without a scheduler. It is preferrable to use this over empty()

More information on [EMPTY](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY)